# Change bundle product price type via database

Tags: magento-1.9, database, mysql, bundle-product

Is it possible to change an existing bundle product from dynamic to fixed price via the database rather than having to create a new product?

Comment: i have run this query but its not working. its showing still dynamic price to No, it sets true in database table though. please let me know what to do?

Answer (score 4):

you can run this query:

```
UPDATE `catalog_product_entity_int`  
SET
    value = 1 
WHERE
    entity_id = 'PRODUCT ID GOES HERE' AND
    attribute_id = (
                SELECT 
                     attribute_id 
                FROM 
                     eav_attribute 
                WHERE 
                     attribute_code = 'price_type'
                )
```

Comment: Do you know it's consequences? I recently had to do the same in Magento2 but the product detail page was still showing the dynamic price.